# Symfony controllers

Tags: rest, api, symfony

I have the task of implementing an Api with FOSRestBundle, but a have told explicitly I can't use inheritance on my controllers, and also i can't use the service container(It's supposed to make the API lighter). Without the extend on the controllers I can't access the AbstractController methods and without the service container my controllers are practically isolated. Is this a viable choice or is an insane? Any advise?

Comment: When they said "don't use the container" I'm guessing they really mean "don't use the container **as a service locator**". My guess is that dependency injection is fine, but you should check with them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not crazy though I would have expected that the same people who told you how not to do things would have also offered some advice on how to do them.

One approach is to break up the ControllerTrait (aka AbstractController) into smaller traits.

[For example:](https://github.com/cerad/zayso4/blob/master/src/Core/RouterTrait.php)

```
trait RouterTrait
{
    /** @var RouterInterface */
    protected $router;

    /** @required NOTE THIS */
    public function setRouter(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }
    protected function generateUrl(
        string $route,
        array $parameters = array(),
        int $referenceType = UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_PATH): string
    {
        return $this->router->generate($route, $parameters, $referenceType);
    }
    protected function redirect($url, $status = 302) : RedirectResponse ...
    protected function redirectToRoute($route, array $parameters = array(), $status = 302) : RedirectResponse ...
```

The @required before the setRouter method is a little used annotation which causes the router service to be automatically injected by the container.

At this point, any controller or any other service that uses the router trait will have access to the router helper functions.

[For example:](https://github.com/cerad/zayso4/blob/master/src/User/Create/UserCreateAction.php)

```
class UserCreateAction implements ActionInterface
{
    use GuidTrait;
    use RouterTrait;
    ...
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
    ...
        return $this->redirectToRoute('reg_person_register');
```

Composition over inheritance can be a good thing.

One final off-topic piece of advice.  There is little or no reason to use FOSRestBundle anymore unless it is to support legacy projects.  The Symfony based [API Platform](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/) is really the goto solution for new projects.